# Regex For All Strings That Pass .NET DateTime.Parse Culture en-US

Tags: .net, regex, datetime

Before you tell me that is a lot of Regex - I know.  Not asking for anyone to write any Regex!  Do you know if someone has already done that Regex?

This will return all the patterns: CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetAllDateTimePatterns()
But this list is not 100% accurate.  There are some patterns that do not parse (yy/mm/dd) and some patterns that parse that are not listed.  Referring to en-US generic DateTime.Parse

What I did was break down the patterns and try and write Regex for each pattern.

```
(^|\s)(3[01]|[12]\d|0?[1-9])\s+(January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December),\s?(19|20)?\d\d(\s+(0?\d|1\d|2[0-4]):[0-6]\d(:[0-6]\d)?(\s+([AP]M|GMT|[+-]\d\d:?\d\d))?)?
        //dd MMMM, yyyy                dddd, dd MMMM, yyyy
        //dd MMMM, yyyy h:mm tt        dddd, dd MMMM, yyyy h:mm tt
        //dd MMMM, yyyy hh:mm tt       dddd, dd MMMM, yyyy h:mm:ss tt
        //dd MMMM, yyyy h:mm:ss tt     dddd, dd MMMM, yyyy hh:mm tt
        //dd MMMM, yyyy hh:mm:ss tt    dddd, dd MMMM, yyyy hh:mm:ss tt
        //dd MMMM, yyyy H:mm           dddd, dd MMMM, yyyy H:mm
        //dd MMMM, yyyy HH:mm          dddd, dd MMMM, yyyy HH:mm
        //dd MMMM, yyyy H:mm:ss        dddd, dd MMMM, yyyy H:mm:ss
        //dd MMMM, yyyy HH:mm:ss       dddd, dd MMMM, yyyy HH:mm:ss

(^|\s)(3[01]|[12]\d|0?[1-9])(/|-)(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)(/|-)\d\d(\s+(0?\d|1\d|2[0-4]):[0-6]\d(:[0-6]\d)?(\s+([AP]M|GMT|[+-]\d\d:?\d\d))?)?
        //dd-MMM-yy 
        //dd-MMM-yy h:mm tt 
        //dd-MMM-yy h:mm:ss tt  
        //dd-MMM-yy hh:mm tt    
        //dd-MMM-yy hh:mm:ss tt 
        //dd-MMM-yy H:mm    
        //dd-MMM-yy HH:mm   
        //dd-MMM-yy H:mm:ss 
        //dd-MMM-yy HH:mm:ss

(^|\s)(January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December)\s(3[01]|[12]\d|0?[1-9])(,\s?|\s)(19|20)?\d\d(\s+(0?\d|1\d|2[0-4]):[0-6]\d(:[0-6]\d)?(\s+([AP]M|GMT|[+-]\d\d:?\d\d))?)?
        //MMMM dd, yyyy             dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy
        //MMMM dd, yyyy h:mm tt     dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy h:mm tt
        //MMMM dd, yyyy h:mm:ss tt  dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy h:mm:ss tt
        //MMMM dd, yyyy hh:mm tt    dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy hh:mm tt
        //MMMM dd, yyyy hh:mm:ss tt dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy hh:mm:ss tt
        //MMMM dd, yyyy H:mm        dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy HH:mm       
        //MMMM dd, yyyy H:mm:ss     dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy H:mm:ss     
        //MMMM dd, yyyy HH:mm       dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss        
        //MMMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss

(^|\s)(19|20)\d\d(/|-)(1[0-2]|0?\d)(/|-)(3[01]|[12]\d|0?[1-9])(\s+(0?\d|1\d|2[0-4]):[0-6]\d(:[0-6]\d)?(\s+([AP]M|GMT|[+-]\d\d:?\d\d))?)?
        /yy/MM/dd   yyyy-MM-dd      
        //yy/MM/dd h:mm tt      yyyy-MM-dd h:mm tt      
        //yy/MM/dd hh:mm tt     yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm tt     
        //yy/MM/dd h:mm:ss tt   yyyy-MM-dd h:mm:ss tt       
        //yy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss tt  yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss tt      
        //yy/MM/dd H:mm         yyyy-MM-dd H:mm     
        //yy/MM/dd HH:mm        yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm        
        //yy/MM/dd H:mm:ss      yyyy-MM-dd H:mm:ss      
        //yy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss     yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss 

(^|\s)(3[01]|[12]\d|0?[1-9])(/|-|/.)(1[0-2]|0?\d)(/|-|/.)(19|20)?\d\d(\s+(0?\d|1\d|2[0-4]):[0-6]\d(:[0-6]\d)?(\s+([AP]M|GMT|[+-]\d\d:?\d\d))?)?
        //fr-FR         
        //dd.MM.yy              dd/MM/yy            dd-MM-yy            dd/MM/yyyy
        //dd.MM.yy H:mm         dd/MM/yy H:mm       dd-MM-yy H:mm       dd/MM/yyyy H:mm
        //dd.MM.yy H:mm:ss      dd/MM/yy H:mm:ss    dd-MM-yy H:mm:ss    dd/MM/yyyy H:mm:ss
        //dd.MM.yy HH' h 'mm    dd/MM/yy HH' h 'mm  dd-MM-yy HH' h 'mm  dd/MM/yyyy HH' h 'mm
        //dd.MM.yy HH.mm        dd/MM/yy HH.mm      dd-MM-yy HH.mm      dd/MM/yyyy HH.mm
        //dd.MM.yy HH:mm        dd/MM/yy HH:mm      dd-MM-yy HH:mm      dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm
        //dd.MM.yy HH:mm:ss     dd/MM/yy HH:mm:ss   dd-MM-yy HH:mm:ss   dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss
```

Comment: Why have you assumed that a regular expression is the right approach? Why not just use `DateTime.TryParse`?

Comment: @JonSkeet Because I need to get the string to parse. As I stated I have text from emails and other native files.  I need to extract the (best) potential datetimes from the text and match does that great.  Like I can make the time component optional ()? and if it is there then it is included.   For email parsing it is much more structured can be smart enough to only parse a line and only certain lines.

Comment: I still don't really follow you. Are you trying to get *all* dates and times from the emails, or just ones from specific headers?

Comment: @JonSkeet Unfortunately I don't have the header.  What I have is a textual extract.  Not all dates but specific dates.  I need the top date and any date of forward or a reply.  Know which lines will (or should) have the forward or reply date but not where in the line.  I don't have control over the date format.   The purpose is an index for email threading.  On the non email text just extract any date for a date index (just a search option).

Comment: Can you post an example e-mail or two?  Are you really looking for any possible date/time pattern?  If you can constrain the patterns you're looking for it will be much easier.

Comment: Yes it would be easier if I could constrain the formats but this 1/2 million emails and many formats.  If the date has any chance of passing DateTime.Parse then I want to pick it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm gonna go out on a limb and assume you'd be fine with not parsing the name of the day, so long as the rest of the date and time is matched... after all, once the date is parsed, the name of the day can be regenerated (it would require additional expression complexity, so I decided to exclude it. That said, I have an expression that seems to do pretty well at finding all the date formats returned by `GetAllDateTimePatterns`, and also several others that might show up as well (not sure if you want these...):

```
Tuesday 20 February 2010
mon, jun 12, 1999
tue, december 9 1901
Friday, February 03, 1900
January 12, 2012
```

(mind you, it does not match the day names, but matches the dates)

This is the expression:

```
(?i)((3[01]|[12]\d|0?[1-9]|\d{4})([\s/.-]))?\b(1[0-2]|0?\d|(jan|febr?)(uary)?|ma(r(ch)?|y)|a(pr(il)?|ug(ust)?)|(sept?|oct|nov|dec)((em|o)ber)?|ju(ne?|ly?))\b(\3|\s)(((?(2)|3[01])|[12]\d|0?[1-9])(?(2)\d\d\b|\b,?\s+(20|19)?\d\d))?\s+(\d+([:.]\d+)+)?
```

I believe it's *fairly* good (I think about as accurate as a human skimming quickly over text), but obviously far from perfect, thus the need for true parsing after the soft match is found. Efficiency of the overall search could be increased by excluding parts of the messages from the search, if possible - if the dates you want to find are all in the header, then only run the expression against the header!

Let me know if it works well enough or if there are any edge cases you find, and I'll see if I can modify it.

Comment: I will try it out.  As far a day of the week if the date is still valid without it then I think I agree.  What it might do it identify an invalid date and that is a good thing.  It was not in the problem but some dates are foreign and that is what I use to set the proper culture. You don't deal with 'GMT' and it turns out that is important as without it is get parsed local time.  They don't use 0000 for GMT.  But still looks good.  I will test it out.

Comment: I am compiling a list of all the main formats now and will post in the question

Comment: @Blam - not sure if you're still looking for this, but I've been working every now and then on an expression, that I'll hopefully post soon

Comment: I like the answer I posted in the question better but your answer helped my get there.